# How to set date value into mongodb with insert method?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-mongodb

Adding data into mongodb with insert method :

```
   $published_at = $faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '-200 days', $endDate = 'now', config('app.timezone'));

   $todayEnd = Carbon::now(config('app.timezone'));

   $data[] = [
      ...
      'published_at' => !empty($published_at->date) ? $published_at->date: null,
      'created_at' => $todayStart,
```

But checking in I see that published_at has null value and created_at has “{}” value.
Which way is valid ?

```
Laravel 9
jenssegers/mongodb 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: jenssegers/mongodb adds mongodb support to Eloquent so you can use Eloquent as normal

Comment: Try adding `published_at` and `created_at` to the `fillable` property of the model if not added.

Comment: If I replace  Model::insert method with Model::create yes, then dates in carbon format are written ok.
I would prefer to use Model::insert as it is quicker and I have a big set of data. 
Is there is a way to pass valid date value with Model::insert ?